# std::thread pass vector element by reference

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdvector, stdthread

I'm trying to figure out why the following works:

```
threaded thr[8] = { threaded(), threaded() ,threaded() ,threaded() ,threaded() ,threaded() ,threaded() ,threaded() };
std::vector<std::thread> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    vec.push_back(std::thread(&threaded::calc, &thr[i], i, num_samples));
}
```

And the following doesn't:

```
std::vector<threaded> thr;
std::vector<std::thread> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    thr.push_back(threaded());
    vec.push_back(std::thread(&threaded::calc, &thr[i], i, num_samples));
}
```

I tried with a std::ref instead of & - it still doesn't work. Here's threaded's definition:

```
struct threaded
{
    float elapsed1 = 0;
    float elapsed2 = 0;
    float res = 0;
    float res_jit = 0;
    void calc(int thread, int num_samples){//do something}
};
```

By doesn't work I mean, that when using vector and &, I get a memory access violation, when I try to use std::ref(thr[i]) instead of &, it doesn't want to compile with the following errors:

```
Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
```

and

```
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
```

If I use just thr[i] it works fine, but I want to modify the values of the threaded class, so I don't really want to pass a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vector `thr` gets bigger with each `push_back` call, eventually exceeding the capacity of a reserved memory region, it needs to reallocate its storage and copy (or move) its elements to the newly allocated space. Once it happens, the objects start to live under new memory addresses, thus the previously obtained addresses are invalidated. In order to prevent relocation, reserve enough space before entering the loop:

```
std::vector<threaded> thr;
thr.reserve(threads);
```

or default-construct all elements at once:

```
std::vector<threaded> thr(threads);
```